# Breaking down a filename into lexicographic based folders

Tags: bash, amazon-s3

Let's say I have thousands of images in a folder in the format `filename_order.jpg`.

- filename are encoded as a 7 digits integer from 0000000 to 9999999
- order is a number between 0 and 9

```
folder/
  6398305_0.jpg
  6398305_1.jpg
  6398305_2.jpg
  ...
  6399305_0.jpg
```

Is there an easy way to sort them into equality repartitioned folders based on the filenames?

```
folder/
  6/3/9/
     8/3/0/5/
        6398305_0.jpg
        6398305_1.jpg
        6398305_2.jpg
  ...
     9/3/0/7/
        6399307_0.jpg
```

Is there a way to do the reverse operation as well: given a nested tree structure bringing it back to level 1 only.

The goal is being able to store them in S3 in an efficient way for millions of images.

Thank you.

Comment: Since you have a large number of files, you will want to avoid things like `mv 1* 1/; mv 2* 2/; ...`, cause this might fail on a large number of files (to many arguments for the `mv` command.  You will have to use `find` for that.  Better yet write something in perl or even C that will loop through your files at a rather faster speed to create your directories and move the files into them.  Filesystem speed will be the limiting factor here (and bash is slower than most on large number of files).

Comment: will `filename` always be exactly 7 numeric/digits? more than 7? less than 7? other than digits? what do you mean by `reverse operation` (example?)?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I have explicited the requirements in the question.

Comment: For thousands of images, I wouldn't bother.  There's no realistic performance penalty for thousands of objects sharing one prefix.  Even in the case of millions of objects, it's only an issue if you're talking about processing tens of thousands of items per second.

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments, I tried to answer my own question is a naive way below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesting a flat folder,

```
cp -R flat_folder/ nested_folder/
cd nested_folder/

for f in *_[0-9].jpg
do
    filename=${f%.*}
    extension=${f##*.}
    number=${filename%_*}
    index=${filename##*_}

    folder=$(echo $number | sed 's/\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)/\1\/\2\/\3\/\4\/\5\/\6\/\7/')
    mkdir -p $folder
    mv $f $folder/
done
```

Flattening a nested folder,

```
cd nested_folder/
find . -name "*.jpg" -exec cp {} ../flat_folder/ \;
```

Answer (score 1):

This would do it in pure Bash:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# extglob needed to expand number into a serie of folders path
shopt -s extglob

# Starting folder name
folder=folder
# Iterate all *.jpg files in folder
for file in "$folder/"*.jpg; do

  # Remove leading directory path from file to get basename
  basename="${file##*/}"

  # Remove everything ater first _ to get only numbers
  numbers="${basename%_*}"

  # Insert / before each number to create a directory path from numbers
  # Need Bash extglob
  dir="$folder${numbers//?()/\/}"

  # Create the directory path
  echo mkdir -p "$dir"

  # move file to its directory
  echo mv "$file" "$dir/"
done
```

Remove the `echo` if the output matches your expectations.

Comment: Interesting, in my self solution which was similar, I used `sed` instead of your line `dir="$folder${numbers//?()/\/}`. I will have a look at yours